# is there a way to find the timeouted fd in libevent?

Tags: libevent

By using *[libevent-2.x](http://libevent.org/)*, there was a option `EV_TIMEOUT` that labels timeout on specific `fd`:

```
event_set(&ev, fd, EV_READ | EV_TIMEOUT, worker, priv_data);
```

By setting the timeout to 5 minutes, the fd will set to be timeout by server. I need the hint to free the `priv_data` or do some statistic on server side, is there was a way to find the timeout `fd` only by setting the `EV_TIMEOUT` option(e.g., callback)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding this part of your question "only by setting the `EV_TIMEOUT` option. The rest of it, I think I am able to answer for you.

There is a way that you can check to see if the timeout event caused the event to return to the callback.

Let's say your callback prototype looks like this

`(evutil_socket_t fd, short what, void *arg)`

Then you can check for a timeout on the `fd` by doing: `(what&EV_TIMEOUT)`

The relevant types are defined in `<event2/event.h>`.

In case this doesn't answer your question, you can find a lot of relevant info here, for example: http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref4_event.html